# ctypes: printf returns length which is int instead of the string

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I'm using ctypes and loading msvcrt.dll in Python 2.5.

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libname = 'msvcrt.dll'
>>> libc = CDLL(libname)
>>> libc.printf("Hello World\n")
12
>>>
```

Why doesn't it print `Hello World`?

Comment: If you run it on console, it should work. However, if you run it on IDLE, Spyder or Jupyter notebook, it would not as the "standard output" is not what `printf()` sees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C `printf()` function itself is defined to return the number of characters printed to the output. This is the value that Python receives when you call `libc.printf()`.

The [`ctypes` tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#calling-functions-continued) provides information on why the output from `printf()` may not work within your Python REPL (my psychic debugging skills indicate that you're running the Windows GUI IDLE).

Comment: But some docs I read says that it should work like that in C. Also David Heffernan gets it.

Comment: +1 I bet that Greg's psychic debugging skills are working well today.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Display to console only and not IDLE.

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesn't it print Hello World?

It does in my Python (ActiveState, 2.6), when run from the console:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libc = CDLL('msvcrt.dll')
>>> libc.printf("Hello world\n")
Hello world
12
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi))</sub>

Comment: No, I'm not getting the Hello World line. Any idea why I'm not getting it? Using Python 3.1 I'm getting 1 as output.

Comment: In Python 3.1 you're getting 3.1 as the output because of Unicode. Although I don't know exactly where the mismatch is. Are you running from a real console or from IDLE or some such?

Comment: As an aside, you wouldn't really want to do this ever. You'd be using ctypes (which incidentally is a work of genius) for stuff other than output.

Comment: @jase you are a mean spirited person. Greg and I spend the time to help you and you can't even find the generosity to give out any up votes!

Answer (score 1):

For others who came here and couldn't get this to work on Python 3.x, the reason is [that you must pass a bytes string (b"whatever")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273618/3870025) not a regular python literal string.

So this code works well on my OSX High Sierra:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL('/usr/lib/libc.dylib')
libc.printf(b"Testing: hello world")
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how ctypes works in windows systems, but when I was using ubuntu system, I write like this :  *libc=CDLL("libc.so.6")*
So ,do you have something wrong with your libs?

Comment: The question has already an accepted answer that says "my psychic debugging skills indicate that you're running the Windows GUI IDLE".